# Можно ли и как получить бесплатно Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

Можно ли вообще скачать intellij idea бесплатно и без срока?

Comment: Нет . Можешь пользоваться EAP версией Idea, можешь попытаться найти ключи... не безуспешно кстати )
можешь посмотреть в сторону Visual Studio

Comment: Станьте OpenSource, они без труда дают пак всех своих решений для них. Ну а так, не думаете, что стоит такое спрашивать у авторов софта, а не у незнакомых людей?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете скачать community версию бесплатно, к ней не нужно приобретать ключ: [Ссылка на скачивание с официального сайта](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/idea/download)

Для ultimate версии нужен ключ, но также есть возможность пользоваться после пробного срока, но с автоматическим закрытием IDE каждые 30 минут.

Answer (score 0):

Без срока нет, если ты студент - то просто предоставь доказательства, и будут тебе все их продукты в про версии на один год.